# How to change cursor selection box color Xubuntu 20.04 (Not Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce

[image]

As you can see from the image here my cursor selection box is blue and like many other Linux users I wish to change mine to match my theme. I am running Xubuntu 20.04, NOT Ubuntu 20.04 (don't mind the Ubuntu wallpaper) and I think it has Xfce instead of Gnome. Been away from Linux for a few years and am getting reacquainted not only to Linux but to a slightly different distro. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As I misunderstood your question, I rewrote my answer.

Since you are using XFCE4, the theming of your "rubberband" (as it is called) is part of your selected theme. So you either download a theme that has the correct color for this kind of selection, or you may overwrite it:

Using some test editor (nano, mousepad, vi) create the directory & file in your home directory:
`mkdir -p  .config/gtk-3.0`

`nano .config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

Now define the colors for your rubberband selection:

```
XfdesktopIconView.view .rubberband, .content-view rubberband,treeview.view rubberband, flowbox rubberband, rubberband,.rubberband {
  border: 1px solid #113edc;
  background-color: rgba(255,165,0,0.2);
}
```

The colors are arbitrary, select any you want (either named or rgb).
The background-color should have some transparency, hence the "rgba" keyword.

Comment: I dont need to chand the color of the mouse. I need to change the selection box aka the section that gets highlighted when you click, hold, and drag the mouse. I know it can be changed in terminal by command

Comment: My mistake - updated my answer